# Is there any way the access token created in iOS app can be used for our server to communicate with twitter & facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, ios7, twitter-oauth

I have integrated the latest SDKs of Twitter & Facebook in my iOS project and implemented functionalities to retrieve the access tokens as well.Previously the app was using an OAuth authentication via server for both this social networks,and the server was keeping the associated access tokens for the periodic communications with Twitter & Facebook.

So is there any way the access token created in iOS can be used for our server to communicate with twitter & facebook accounts?

The server side scripts and implemented in python/Django.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not. Just establish a webservice which receives the newly created ("short-lived") access token, exchanges them to long-lived ones and stores them in some database. After that you can use them for your server-side requests.

Have a look here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Comment: Thanks for the information @Tobi.Is there anyway in twitter to do the same thing?

Comment: You mean extending access tokens? AFAIK Twitter's access token do not expire: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#7188

Comment: My question is,is it possible to use the Access token I obtained in the iOS application(authentication with the latest social SDK and access token obtained via reverse auth),for the api communication between our server to twitter.

Comment: Why should it be possible? It described here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#7189